# How to connect USB-C port to USB hub?

Tags: usb-c, usb-hub

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm very new to all of this. I'm trying to connect the upstream port on a 4 port USB hub to a USB type C plug and I'm somewhat confused on how to wire the TX and RX pins. The hub only has one set of TX and RX pins but the USB C plug has two. If I am understand correctly this is because USB C is reversible, so it needs to have a pair on each side of the port, but I am still somewhat confused on what this means for wiring it. Do I just connect the X1 and X2 pins and then send them to the respective pins on the hub, as I have already done in the image, or do I need to do something extra to make this work?

[image: My work in progress schematic]

Comment: It is not possible to connect them because it is impossible without extra chips between connector and chip. There is no CC/VConn detection to detect what is connected and how and in which polarity, and then the chip wires need to be muxed to correct set of pins.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this requires a chip to do some static decision-making.  It is easier just to use a cable to do the converting, it has the chips in the connector to sort it out.

Comment: A few corrections, a chip is required to do some dynamic decision-making, and the cable has no chips in the connector to sort it out. The chips are always right near the receptacle.